# A problem with rendering CSS on mPDF - PHP

Tags: php, html, css, mpdf, html-to-pdf

Okay.

The Problem is kinda weird.

I'm trying to convert HTML page to PDF file and save it.

I'm using mPDF for this. However, CSS rendering isn't going as expected.

I'm not using CSS3. So, I don't think that this is the problem.

Here's a screen shot of how should it be :

[image]

**PDF :**

[image: Goes really wrong]

Thanks in advance.

**HTML :**
https://codepen.io/AKhaled47/pen/omRObM

**CSS :**

```
div.calendar{
  margin:2pc auto;
  padding:0px;
  width:602px;
}
div.calendar div.box{
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    background-color:#890e4f;    
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;  
}
div.calendar div.header{
    line-height:40px;  
    vertical-align:middle;
    position:absolute;
    left:11px;
    top:0px;
    width:582px;
    height:40px;   
    text-align:center;
}
div.calendar div.header a.prev,div.calendar div.header a.next{ 
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;   
    height: 17px;
    display:block;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#FFF;
}
div.calendar div.header span.title{
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:18px;
}
div.calendar div.header a.prev{
    left:0px;
}
div.calendar div.header a.next{
    right:0px;
}
div.calendar div.box-content{
    background: #FFF;
    border:1px solid #890e4f;
    border-top:none;
    border-radius:5px;
    border-top-left-radius:0;
    border-top-right-radius:0;
}
div.calendar ul.label{
    float:left;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
div.calendar ul.label li{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    margin-right:5px;  
    float:left;
    list-style-type:none;
    width:80px;
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    color:#000;
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: transparent;
}
div.calendar ul.dates{
    float:left;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
div.calendar ul.dates li{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    margin-right:5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    line-height:80px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    float:left;
    list-style-type:none;
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
    font-size:25px;
    background-color: #DDD;
    color:#000;
    text-align:center; 
}
:focus{
    outline:none;
}
div.clear{
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with CSS. But one thing I recognized in your code:
are you using deliberately the unit 'pc' (Pica) instead of 'px'(magic css unit) in your first css element? If it is deliberateness, let's have a look at your html code...  Are you using any kind of loop to generate your html?

Comment: 1- Changing pc to px doesn't make any difference.
2- No, I don't. I just used for loops and foreach in calendar class. that's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Float elements are only partially supported in mPDF. For best results, use a HTML table (which is perfectly suitable for a calendar).

See documentation on floats: https://mpdf.github.io/what-else-can-i-do/floating-blocks.html

Comment: Okay, let me try.
Although changing the HTML would be a big deal for this.
But some efforts would be better

Comment: Unfortunately, Goes worse.

Comment: Checked my HTML 4 times for any non closed tags, etc.
It's displaying normal on my web page.
But not in the pdf.

Comment: Not helpful. Update your question with _actual_ HTML code. Just append it, do not rewrite it for the sake of history.

Comment: This is the real HTML code, I didn't take a screenshot of something else.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode - No one will ever reproduce your problem from an image of PHP code. Also see MCVE.

Comment: Ok, I couldn't update my post with html code as it has too many lines of codes.
So, I've added link to codepen of my HTML code.
I've tried to remove php from it to post in code pen.
I don't know if that really helps or not. But, I've tried.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188845/discussion-between-finwe-and-hema-elmasry).